# Create/destroy or show/hide Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I have a situation in which I need to show/hide a fragment based on a dynamic variable.  My question is should I create the fragment once, and then show/hide based on the variable.  Or should I destroy/create it each time?

Create the fragment

```
Fragment alertFragment = new AlertFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(android.R.id.content, alertFragment).commit();
```

After this should I call show/hide each time?

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
          .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
          .show(alertFragment)  // or hide
          .commit();
```

Seems like a lot of work to show/hide something each time.  Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that depends on weather it matters for your application if your `Fragment` is destroyed or not.

**If it doesn't matter at all, simply replace** the `Fragment` everytime by a new one. This is the simplest solution and does not require any logic.

```
Fragment f = new Fragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content, f).commit();
```

Comment: Not sure replace is really what I want. I want to create/remove or show/hide. Not sure what I would be replacing with in the case that I want to hide.

Comment: That's what replace does. It essentially `remove()` the current fragment and then `add()` the new fragment in the container.